# ggplot: How to change the y-value into a text in a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

does anyone of you know, how I can change the y-value (see in the plot) from 1 to 5 into a "text" like "Strongly Agree" "Agree" "Undecided" "Disagree" "Strongly Disagree". I have tried a lot of scale_y_continuous or scale_y_discrete combination without success. Any help is welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work for you:

```
  require(ggplot2)
  data <- data.frame(value = rnorm(40, mean = 2, sd = 3),
                     variable = c(rep('A', 20), rep('B', 20)), 
                     group = rep(c('G1', 'G2'), 20))
  yLabs <- c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Undecided", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree")
  ggplot(data, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill=group)) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1,2,3,4,5), labels=yLabs)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Prradep, thank you very much for the information. this is/was exactly what I´m looking for! Works perfect! Best portas525

Comment: @portas525 If this is the solution you are looking for, then please accept this as the answer so that others know that you found the solution. For more info on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)